# tableView reloadData off of delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Have a right view controller that slides in and out over the main view controller. This right view controller has a table in it to contain the passed information from the main.

I can access and pass the data to the controller from the main without issue but in the right view I need to then bind the data passed to it from the main.

The problem is that even though I try binding the data after the view comes into focus it gives nil on the `tableView.reloadData()`.

`RightViewController` has 2 functions that are used by the main

```
func loadAlerts(){
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
func setAlerts(alerts: Alerts){
    self.alerts = alerts
}
```

`Alerts` is just a custom object. It does contain values. `self.alerts` is a class variable.

`MainViewController` calls these 2 functions this way

```
self.rightViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as! RightViewController
```

Set the data after getting it from the api call

```
if let count = self.alerts?.Alerts.count {
        if count == 0 {
            return
        }
        //set on controller
        rightViewController.setAlerts(alerts: self.alerts!)
    }
```

This is defined at class level like

```
private var rightViewController: RightViewController!
```

Then I have a delegate defined for when the right controller is opened from a gesture and it calls like this

```
func rightDidOpen() {
    rightViewController.loadAlerts()
}
```

This works fine for everything but the a tableView. Even by telling the tableView to load on the main thread like so

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Didn't change anything. At this point the alerts has values.

I don't mind refactoring the entire thing if need be so any ideas, thoughts or info of how I can get this to work is appreciated. If more info is needed just let me know.

--

Here the table delegate and source defined

```
class RightViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

and from front end assigned to the uicontroller (its calle Alerts Scene). Forgot to mention that if I do the api call directly in the right controller it works fine but I'm trying to reduce api calls so am refactoring this.

[image]

Here are the methods. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

```
//MARK: Tableview delegates
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = alerts?.Alerts.count{
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let alertD = alerts?.Alerts[indexPath.row] {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AlertTableViewCell") as! AlertTableViewCell
        cell.name.text = alertD.Summary
        cell.icon.image = Helpers.listImage24dp(id: alertD.TOA)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.name.textColor = UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Can you add `UITableView` delegate/dataSource methods?

Comment: I am wondering why in your picture the dataSource and delegate are connected to Alerts instead of RightTableView (or whatever name you give to your Right Table View Controller Scene in Document Outline ) ?

Comment: Alerts is the name of the uiviewcontroller.

Comment: So show us your dataSource and delegate methods' code.